# How display data from API in dropdown 2 depending on what is selected in dropdown 1

Tags: angular, typescript, api, frontend

I have two dropdown. In both, data is receiving from API. Base on what is selected in first dropdown, will appear data in dropdown 2.

**sidebar.component.html** :

```
<div class="dropdown  ml-auto">
    <select (change)=selectedHandlerProjectName($event) class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="margin-left: -10px;border-left-width:15px;padding-left:11px;padding-right: 14px;margin-right: 12px;border-right-width: 12px">
        <option value = "default">Select project</option>
        <option *ngFor = "let project of selectProject" value = {{projectName}}>{{project.projectName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="dropdown  m3-auto">
    <select (change)=selectedHandlerProjectVariantName($event) class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle">
        <option value = "default">Select variant project</option> 
        <option *ngFor = "let project of selectVariantProject" value = {{projectVariantName}}>{{project.projectVariantName}}</option>  
     </select>
</div>
```

**sidebar.component.ts** :

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  selectProject : Project;
  selectVariantProject: ProjectVariant;

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) { }


  getSelectedProject(): void{  
    this.projectService.getProjects()
      .subscribe(selectProject => this.selectProject= selectProject);
  }

  getSelectedVariantProject(id: number): void{
     this.projectService.getProjectVariant(id)
      .subscribe(selectVariantProject => this.selectVariantProject = selectVariantProject);
  }

  //methods to get dropdown values
  dropDownProjectName: string = '';
  selectedHandlerProjectName(event : any)
  {
    if(event.target.value != 'default') { this.dropDownProjectName = event.target.value;
     }
    else {this.dropDownProjectName = null;}
   // this.getSelectedVariantProject(2);
  }

  dropDownProjectVariantName: string = '';
  selectedHandlerProjectVariantName(event : any)
  {
    if(event.target.value != 'default') { this.dropDownProjectVariantName = event.target.value;}
    else {this.dropDownProjectVariantName = null;}

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSelectedProject();
      }
}
```

**The ProjectVariant API** must be call with the **value** of what is selected in first dropdown.

```
getSelectedVariantProject(id: number): void{
     this.projectService.getProjectVariant(id)
      .subscribe(selectVariantProject => this.selectVariantProject = selectVariantProject);
  }
```

How to make this dependency and pass the value of what is selected in first dropdown as argument in **getSelectedVariantProject(id: number)**

Comment: Call getSelectedVariantProject() inside selectedHandlerProjectName(), then everytime you select one item in dropdown one, it will call getSelectedVariantProject() to get this.selectVariantProject and show data in DOM.

also you cand add a <ng-container *ngIf="selectVariantProject"> before and after the option of the second dropdown

Comment: When i put in first dropdown  in select (change)=getSelectedVariantProject() I don't know how to pass the argument to represent an Id of options selected . Something like that getSelectedVariantProject(2).